# JPA : Forcing eager load only for a query

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Please, my JPA Query is created using CriteriaQuery and CriteriaBuilder like this:

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<TaskInfo> cq = cb.createQuery(TaskInfo.class);
Root<TaskInfo> from = cq.from(TaskInfo.class);
cq.select(from);
...
from.get("task").get("id").in(taskList)
...
```

I want to make sure that I eagerly load the whole graph of objects so that later on I don't have proxies instead of objects when I close the JPA Session.:
TaskInfo->Task->TaskData->and so on until object X.

A way to do it is this

```
for(TaskInfo ti : tiList){
    ti.getTask().getTaskData().getSomethingElse().getX();
}
```

But this sucks, right? And I don't want to change fetching in general, but only for this specific query. How can I do it? Thanks & cheers

---

Thanks for the help. But
Task has a property

```
PeopleAssignments peopleAssignments
```

and PeopleAssignments has a property

```
List<OrganizationalEntity> businessAdministrators
```

so this works

```
from.fetch("task").fetch("peopleAssignments") // Returns a SingularAttributeJoin
```

but if I do this

```
from.fetch("task").fetch("peopleAssignments").fetch("businessAdministrators")
```

I get:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.SingularAttributeImpl cannot be cast to javax.persistence.metamodel.ManagedType

I think it's because this time I'm trying to fetch List. Do you know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

you can add a `fetch()` to your query to guarantee the load of other lazy linked objects as [described here](http://webdev.apl.jhu.edu/~jcs/ejava-javaee/coursedocs/605-784-site/docs/content/html/jpa-query-criteria.html#jpa-query-criteria-fetchjoins) in chapter 5.6.2 or [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-from-fetch) in chapter 9.3.3.

```
Root<TaskInfo> from = cq.from(TaskInfo.class);
Join<TaskInfo, Task> task = from.fetch("task");
task.fetch("id");
...
```

I did not test it by myself, so I hope this works.

Comment: Thanks. but
Task has a
PeopleAssignments peopleAssignments
and PeopleAssignments has a
List<OrganizationalEntity> businessAdministrators
so this works
from.fetch("task").fetch("peopleAssignments") // Returns a SingularAttributeJoin

but if I do this
from.fetch("task").fetch("peopleAssignments").fetch("businessAdministrators")
I get:
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.ejb.metamodel.SingularAttributeImpl cannot be cast to javax.persistence.metamodel.ManagedType
I think it's because this time I'm trying to fetch List. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know.